# Convert array with json data into an array with field and value property

Tags: angular, angular2-services, primeng, angular2-components

I have fetched data from an external json file into an array using these two separate file.
**serviceFile**

```
getProjectNames(){
return this._http.get(this._url)
.map((response:Response) => response.json())
}
```

**componentFile**

```
ngOnInit(){
this.roadmapGeneratorService.getProjectNames()
.subscribe(resProjectNames => this.projectNames = resProjectNames) 
}
```

Now i have to show the values of `projectNames` into `p-dropdown element of primeng`. To do this I need to convert/copy `projectNames` array into array with label and value field something like this.

```
for(let index=0;index<this.len;index++)
{
this.portNames.push ({label: this.projectNames[index], value: ''});
}
```

but it is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(let key in this.projectNames)
{
    this.portNames.push({label: this.projectNames[key], value: this.projectNames[key]});
}
```

Comment: This is my json file [
    {
        "f1": "Project1",
        "f2": "Project2",
    }
]

Comment: so what i should write in place of label_field according to your answer